# Ciclo for con números pares

Tags: javascript

Soy nueva en esto y voy aprendiendo sobre la marcha. Mi duda es la siguiente:

Al momento de correr las siguientes líneas código me marca *error*. Agradecería si me pudieran compartir mis errores.

> Instrucción:
>
> Realizar una función llamada `pasandoPorLosPares()` que muestre por consola ***acá `i` tiene el valor de `x`*** por cada valor **PAR** que va tomando `i` desde *0 hasta 6* (inclusive).

> Te recordamos que debes prestar especial atención con los espacios. En el ejercicio debe haber un solo espacio entre cada palabra.

```js
function pasandoPorLosPares() {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 8; i = i + 2) {
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de" + i);
  }
}
console.log(pasandoPorLosPares());
```

¿De qué otra manera lo puedo realizar utilizando el `%` para que me indique qué es número par?

---

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, no creí que alguien responda jejeje :)
En la instrucción menciona que se debe de utilizar el **%** (modulo) y que en la tercera parte del ciclo se debería poner. También que "La ejecución de la función pasandoPorLosPares debe iterar un total de 4 veces"
He intentado con :

```js
function  pasandoPorLosPares (){ 
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        if ((i%2) == 0){
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de"+ i);
        }else{}
}
}
console.log(pasandoPorLosPares());
```

pero la pagina donde estan los ejercicios no lo corre. Ya no encuentro otra solución.

Comment: ¿Y qué error obtienes?

Comment: Como comenta el compañero @BetaM, ¿cuál es el error que obtienes? El código parece funcionar como se espera. Adicionalmente creo que sería bueno indicar con qué lenguaje estás aprendiendo, aunque se puede deducir, no está de más.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hay un primer ejemplo con el problema y los demás ejemplos con las correcciones hechas. El primero con el problema, que es el que copié de tu pregunta y el otro con la corrección. Debes leer los comentarios que se encuentran en el código. Allí se señalan los problemas.

### Está bien, solo que hay un detalle

Tus líneas de código están bien, pero falta un detalle que debes tomar en cuenta:

- Estás llamando a la función `pasandoPorLosPares()` que no devuelve ningún valor desde un `console.log`. Por lo tanto, te mostrará en la consola un `undefined`.

Observe la parte comentada del siguiente ejemplo que muestra el problema:

```js
function pasandoPorLosPares() {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 8; i = i + 2) {
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de" + i);
  }
}

// Esta es la línea que causa el problema, provocando
// que la consola muestra «undefined» al final:
console.log(pasandoPorLosPares());
```

El problema está en `console.log(pasandoPorLosPares());` y se corrige así:

```js
function pasandoPorLosPares() {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 8; i = i + 2) {
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de " + i);
  }
}

// Ejecutando la función directamente:
pasandoPorLosPares()
```

Ejecutando la función directamente, ya que estás utilizando `console.log` en el bucle **for**.

Para que el bucle cumpla con lo siguiente, cito:

> Realizar una función llamada `pasandoPorLosPares()` que muestre por consola ***acá `i` tiene el valor de `x`*** por cada valor **PAR** que va tomando `i` desde *0 hasta 6* (inclusive).

Bastaría con definirla así:

```js
function pasandoPorLosPares() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i += 2) {
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de " + i);
  }
}

// Ejecutando la función directamente:
pasandoPorLosPares()
```

Donde `i += 2` incrementará de **2 en 2** a `i`.

Si partimos de la siguiente premisa:

> ¿De qué otra manera lo puedo realizar utilizando el `%` para que me indique qué es número par?

Podrías definirla así:

```js
function pasandoPorLosPares() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log("acá i tiene el valor de " + i);
    }
  }
}

// Ejecutando la función directamente:
pasandoPorLosPares()
```

Pero, nuestro bucle ya no iteraría cuatro (04) veces, sino 7, y como una parte de los números que se comprueban no son múltiplos de 2 parecerá que iteró cuatro (04) veces gracias a la comprobación hecha con el módulo `%`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las observaciones, me es de mucha ayuda en el camino del aprendizaje. Gracias y tenga lindo día!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hola no sé si te sirve pero creo que te tiraba error porque en la consigna no pide que llames la función nuevamente. borrando

```js
function  pasandoPorLosPares (){ 
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        if (i%2 == 0){
    console.log("acá i tiene el valor de "+ i);
                      }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

espero no llegar tarde, tal vez puedas probar con esto ;)

```
function pasandoPorLosPares(){
    for(var i = 0; i<=6; i = i +2){
        console.log("acá i tiene el valor de " +i);
    }
}

pasandoPorLosPares()
```

Comment: Tu respuesta se enriquecerá mucho si además le explicas tu código, checa [answer]